# Why the ip address value is and with int 255

Tags: java, string, binary, inetaddress

I have a simple program to find my IP address and convert it to a String. 
Why is the `b[i]` value with `(int)255` below?

```
public class FirstSocketProgramming {  

 public static void main (String arg[]){  

  InetAddress local = null;  

  try {  

   local = InetAddress.getLocalHost();  

  } catch (UnknownHostException e){  

   System.err.println   

      ("Identity Crisis!");  

   System.exit(0);  

  }  

 byte[] b = local.getAddress();  

System.out.println (b.toString());  
System.out.println (b.length);  
 String strAddress="";  

 for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++)  

   strAddress += ((int)255&b[i]) + ".";  

 System.out.println ("Local = " + strAddress);  

 }  

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`byte` data type is based on [Two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) binary signed number representation with a value range from -128 to +127.

Positive values from 0 to 127 have it's most significant bit equal to 0 representing `+`.
Here binary representation is the same as it's numeric value, for example `byte 00000100 = int 4`

Negative values from -128 to -1 have it's most significant bit equal to 1 representing `-`
However in negative range, Two's complement binary representation is **NOT** the same as it's numeric value, for example you would expect `byte 10000100` to be equal to `int 132`, but is actually `-124`.
Simply casting a `byte` to `int` won't help.

Casting just widens 1 byte to 4 btytes,  `10000100 ==> 11111111111111111111111110000100` which is equal to -124, not 132, because `int` data type is also based on Two's complement. Casting `byte` into `int` is a step in the right direction, however  you also need to get rid of all these ones in front. `255&b[i]` trick achieves that.

This is what happens in `255&b[i]`:
According to conversion rules defined in the the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2) `&` bitwise operator first converts it's operands to int, which means `255&b[i]` is the same as `((int)255)&((int)b[i])`. When byte is cast to int it just gets wider:

`10000100 = byte -124  ==> 11111111111111111111111110000100 = int -124`

Then bitwise AND is performed.

```
11111111111111111111111110000100 = int -124 
&
00000000000000000000000011111111 = int 255
--------------------------------
00000000000000000000000010000100 = int 132
```

Final result is an `int 132`

Answer (score 3):

It's converting the signed byte to an integer so that you get the full range of (unsigned) 8-bits, instead of showing a negative number for values over 127.

In Java, since bytes are signed, the max value for a byte is 127. So lets say the number is 128. In an unsigned byte this would be represented as 10000000b. However, with 2's complement negative numbers, this becomes -128. Doing 255 & b[i] coerces the value to an integer (32-bit) and zeroes out the high bits so you get 128 instead of -128.

Comment: Good answer, but I'll have to critique your wording a little. "the full range of 8-bits" is still respected with -128 to 127 except it is shifted due to a bit acting as a sign bit. The idea is right, though.

Comment: Explanation for the -1 please?

Comment: Wasn't me, I think this is valid as well.

Comment: I figured it wasn't you. No worries.

Answer (score 3):

The address is written as a set of bytes, from 0 to 255. Java interprets each byte as a *signed* one from -128 to 127. Thus, forming a string from the bytes as signed ones would be meaningless, for example `-18.14.87.-45`. This does not match the IP representation.

```
(int)255&b[i]
```

casts `b[i]` to an `int` while widening it, thus ignoring sign and reading it as unsigned. The `(int)` is frivolous as `255` is already interpreted as something wider than 8 bits. The `0-255` value is concatenated aftwerwards. You thus get an IP like `192.168.1.200`(note that this address does not match the erronous one given before).

As a general thing doing `255&foo` (or any `2^n-1` for integer n, like 65536, or even in hex like `0xFF`) is an attempt to cast bit lengths safely.

Comment: Well it works even if "(int)" widening is removed meaning (255&b[i]) itself is sufficient so widening is not necessary here it seems.

Comment: @dganesh2002 Yet it is there, so I'm answering in its context. "The `(int)` is frivolous as `255` is already interpreted as something wider than 8 bits."

Comment: Can the downvoter please explain the reasoning? (@dganesh2002 It was fixed)

Comment: I wonder if the answer is good or it's becauses the Java tag. You already have 3(!) upvotes... I think it's because the Java.

Comment: Why not use toString()?

Comment: @Phpdna Because there's already an implicit numeric-to-string conversion.

Comment: @Phpdna Yes, as one of the operands is a string. `+ "."` can qualify as well.

Answer (score 0):

The ip address is logical and with the subnet_mask to find the net_id and the host_id. In the example it's the same but very unusual. The subnet_mask can be used to carve out many net_id. Read here for an example: http://www.garykessler.net/library/subnet_masks.html.

Comment: How does this have anything to do with the specifics of the Java cast? This is just a summary of what addresses and masks can do.

Comment: Subnet-mask is also 255. How do you know it's a cast thing?

Comment: Read the use of it in context in the code. It's used here in another fashion than you describe. A subnet mask just has 255 due to its bitmask properties, here it's applied to *all* of the bytes. A downvote in spite isn't a real logical move either. I did not downvote you at all, if you'd notice.

Comment: Hmm. Not sure. My answer can be true,too. It can cast to integer without the and?

Comment: A byte value that is signed negative cast directly will *remain* negative in Java, so *no*.

Comment: BTW. when I downvote I get negative reputation hence don't tell me about logic.

Comment: Why not use toString()?